# how to make an ontology for a Real-Time-Strategy game

Tags: computer-science, ontology

I'm looking to make an ontology for a project. It's my first time doing something like this. I have downloaded protege, but don't know what to do now. 
I have to make it on information collected from a game (i.e the unit type, unit relationships, etc...) which is based on real time strategy game which I don't understand.

Making the ontology the graph type thing in protege is not a problem I've check some tutorial I think I could manage that the only problem is I don't know were to start: how do I structure the information and what info do I need to make this ontology.

Can some please help out if they know what to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at [this site](http://www.gameontology.org/). It gives you informations about how to study the ontology of a game, depending on its features and genre. It is divided into sections: for each section you have a list of actions available. Each action has its own page (it's like a wiki).

Anyway, I think you'll need to think about what do you want to do: that site won't give you everything you need. My suggestion is to write on paper and do some brainstorming first without using an application, checking the site for reference or to see how they organize things in sections.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work anymore; or rather, the content has changed.